# Codename one image issue

Tags: user-interface, codenameone

I'm currently creating an app using Codename one but when I add images to a button the quality is compromised. The icons are very high quality png files so they are not the issue. Does anyone know how I can add the images and maintain quality?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you set the image as the background instead of setting them as an icon which defaults to scaling.

Try scale to fill background behavior setting or writing a more descriptive question. I would also suggest using multi-images http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---fetch-an-image-from-the-resource-file---add-a-multiimage